# How can I see logs of Peewee transaction/session operations like COMMIT, BEGIN and RELEASE CONNECTION?

Tags: python, orm, peewee

How can I see logs of transaction/session operations in Peewee ORM? Like COMMIT, BEGIN, RELEASE CONNECTION?

I have used the python logging module like is described in Peewee documentation ( https://peewee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/peewee/database.html#logging-queries )

But following code display in terminal only operations related to SQL queries:

```py
        logger = logging.getLogger('peewee')
        logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

I need to check when commit operations are executed.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to subclass and override those methods on your database, e.g.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('peewee.transactions')

class MyDatabase(SqliteDatabase):
    def begin(self):
        logger.debug('beginning transaction')
        return super(MyDatabase, self).begin()

    # etc. for rollback(), commit().
```

Technically these should be occurring wherever you tell them to, e.g. via an `atomic()` block. See the docs, which are hopefully quite thorough: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#managing-transactions